# centering menu in different resolutions

Tags: css, margin, centering

http://www.mammacoil.com/

Im struggling with centering this menu, ive tried the margin auto css and it doesnt seem to be working. Can someone help please.

Would it be easier for me to put this at 100% and then margin auto??

```
#access {
clear: both;
margin-top: -20%;;
margin-left: 15%;
width: 100%;
font-family: SansitaOne;
font-weight: 100;
text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
height: 43px;
text-align: center;

}
#access ul {
font-size: 18px;
list-style: none;
}
#access li {
position: relative;
float: left;
}
```

thankyou in advance.

Kirsty

Comment: Please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this by `margin:0 auto;` it will work for every  resolution

and set width

```
#access {
    clear: both;
    font-family: SansitaOne;
    font-weight: 100;
    height: 43px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #000000;
    width: 960px;              <-----set this
}
```

Comment: Hi Null pointer, i tried this and it still didnt center the access div content :S

Comment: @KirstyHarris try ` text-align: center;` on #access div

Comment: @ Nullpointer... its already in there as above in the #access?

Comment: see it has now set it below menu bk, not where i wanted it :S

Comment: pointer, if u check out my website above. The menu which is contained in #access div, its off center and i want this centering

Comment: as i have a rollover effect on it also ... so i need some positioning

Comment: margin: 0 auto; not working because width:100% use width:960px and margin:0 auto;

Comment: ive just put it back in the top wrapper div, but its still not centered. Would it be easier to center the top wrapper?

Comment: @KirstyHarris set the width to the #access div

Comment: @Harshit is this going to not make my wrapper not full width thou... as i have a bg on this?

Comment: Hi both, i amended the #access width to 960px with the auto margin option and it seemed to work. Thanks for the advance all :)